# install luaEclipse error

Tags: eclipse, lua

I try in stall luaEclipse on Eclipse follow the instruciton

```
http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation
```

but it reported:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.keplerproject.ldt.feature_x64.feature.group [1.2.0.200802220021] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

but I do not know what the filter means?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't select by error both lueclipse entries in the update site?
See [this thread for instance](http://lists.luaforge2.net/pipermail/kepler-project/2011-January/004575.html):

> I am a fool,...
>   There where two entries named "Lua Development Tool" in the `LuaEclipse 1.2` package, **32 and 64 versions**.
>
> It was impossible to install both.