# Cannot install LuaEclipse on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ide, lua

Note: Already asked [in this post (asked on StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672131/install-luaeclipse-error). However, the problem is not solved.

When I install LuaEclipse by following [this instruction](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation), for LuaEclipse 1.2, after input software's URL, check LuaEclipse 1.2 and click Next, it always reports something like this:

> Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not
>   satisfiable   org.keplerproject.ldt.feature.feature.group
>   [1.2.0.200802220021] cannot be installed in this environment because
>   its filter is not applicable.

Here are what I tried:

1. With Eclipse for Windows 64bit: I check Lua Development Tool (for 32bit), it failed, so I check 64bit version (without checking 32bit version), but it still failed. I tried checked all, and... it failed again.
2. Then I downloaded Eclipse for Windows 32bit (yes, it can run on Windows 7 64bit, and I searched with Google, someone solves the problem by using 32bit version of Eclipse), and tried every possible check like 1., but they all failed!
3. I tried 1.1, and it installed successfully, but I need an important feature in 1.2 version!

Has anyone experimence this problem? Or can you tell me any LUA plugin for Eclipse that support documentation (I mean, the auto-completion for syntax, ...)?

Comment: I know it wasn't your question, so I am just commenting. Have you tried the Lua plugin for Intellij IDEA? (I am the author). Anyhow, here is the link for more info: https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home

Comment: Yes, I'm using it right now. But IntelliJ is somehow... worse than Eclipse. The document only show hints in tooltip, not expand the parameters.

Comment: @sylvanaar I'm trying to parse the Corona API, but with functions' parameters. Your luadoc file is quite complex!

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to be flexible, and not require special syntax.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out http://eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/ they seem to be picking up where LuaEclipse left off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making @sylvanaar's comment an answer:

> Also, you might want to check out http://eclipse.org/koneki/ldt they seem to
>   be picking up where LuaEclipse left off.